# Move a Shape within an Excel Worksheet based on Input Data

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking at making a timeline within Excel that moves a 'window' (the white oval) along the timeline based on the date. 
[image]

What I'm looking at doing is in VBA:

1. Setting a scale (where the whole arrow is a year)
2. Setting the oval's initial position
3. Setting the oval's new position (based on how far down the timeline the date is)

I'm completely new to VBA and was wondering if someone could please point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim shp As Shape
For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    If shp.Type = 1 Then
        shp.Delete
    End If
Next shp

ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape Type:=msoShapeOvalCallout, Left:=100, Top:=100, Width:=200, Height:=150
ActiveSheet.Shapes(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "Hello people!"

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"))

For i = 1 To 25 Step 1
    ActiveSheet.Shapes(1).IncrementLeft -4
    ActiveSheet.Shapes(1).IncrementTop i
    Application.Wait (Now + 0.000009)
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Noob question, how would I input data?

Comment: If I had a date at the top left cell of the worksheet

Comment: How do you determine which date is current date?

Comment: If the length of arrow = 365, the input data would be what day of the year it is i.e 24 for today
Which in theory would place the oval window to the corresponding point on the arrow

Answer (score 0):

How about?

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim shp As Shape
For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    If shp.Type = 1 Then
        shp.Delete
    End If
Next shp

If ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = 1 Then
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape Type:=msoShapeOvalCallout, Left:=100, Top:=0, Width:=200, Height:=150
End If

If ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = 2 Then
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape Type:=msoShapeOvalCallout, Left:=100, Top:=50, Width:=200, Height:=150
End If

'and so on...
End Sub
```